# Why is PostgreSQL doing a sequential scan instead of a index scan in this query?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I'm working with OpenStreetMap osm2pgsql database. One of its table (planet_osm_line) have two indexed fields: osm_id (int, primary key) and way (postgis geometry).

I'd like to find which streets intersect with a specific street, which I know by it's osm_id. So I do:

```
SELECT name, * FROM planet_osm_line
WHERE highway IS NOT NULL
AND osm_id != 126021312
AND ST_Intersects(way, (SELECT way FROM planet_osm_line WHERE osm_id = 126021312 LIMIT 1))
```

And it takes about 10 seconds to run.

If instead, I take that subquery out and run it separately, it looks about like this:

```
SELECT name, * FROM planet_osm_line
WHERE highway IS NOT NULL
AND osm_id != 126021312
AND ST_Intersects(way, '010200002031BF0D000D000000E17...')
```

And it takes about 0.47 seconds to run.

Running EXPLAIN on the first and the second query gives me a hint about the difference.

First:

```
Seq Scan on planet_osm_line  (cost=2.09..614596.67 rows=628706 width=1079)
  Filter: ((highway IS NOT NULL) AND (osm_id <> 126021312) AND st_intersects(way, $0))
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.09 rows=1 width=249)
          ->  Index Scan using planet_osm_line_pkey on planet_osm_line planet_osm_line_1  (cost=0.43..3.76 rows=2 width=249)
                Index Cond: (osm_id = 126021312)
```

Second:

```
Index Scan using planet_osm_line_index on planet_osm_line  (cost=0.41..4.25 rows=1 width=1079)
  Index Cond: (way && '010200002031BF0D000D000000E17...'::geometry)
  Filter: ((highway IS NOT NULL) AND (osm_id <> 126021312) AND _st_intersects(way, '010200002031BF0D000D000000E17...'::geometry))
```

Why is it that PostgreSQL is doing a seq scan on the first and a index scan on the second? Is there a way to solve this problem without issuing two queries?

Comment: `(SELECT way FROM planet_osm_line WHERE osm_id = 126021312 LIMIT 1))` is IMnsHO a terrible way to emulate an `EXISTS(...)` (or JOIN)

Comment: Did you run `VACUUM ANALYZE`?

Comment: wildplasser: yes, I'm emulating a JOIN there.

rightfold: I didn't, but I did now. It continues to do the seq scan on the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your query so that instead of having a sub-query within ST_Intersects, you instead have a cross join in the FROM, which will then be restricted by the intersects in the WHERE (which also implicitly does a &&, ie, bounding box check, which will hit the spatial index).

```
SELECT name, osm.* 
FROM planet_osm_line osm, 
  (SELECT way FROM planet_osm_line WHERE osm_id = 126021312 LIMIT 1) line
WHERE highway IS NOT NULL
AND osm_id != 126021312
AND ST_Intersects(osm.way, line.way);
```

Comment: Yes, that works fast too. The EXPLAIN shows it has the same meaning as the other query I posted above (with explicit JOIN).

Comment: Your query doesn't work as is, could you fix it? I changed the ST_Intersects to make it work: ST_Intersects(osm.way, line.way).

Comment: Sure, fixed, sorry, didn't have any way to test.

Answer (score 1):

This way seems to work fine (answers partially my question):

```
SELECT l1.name, l1.*
FROM planet_osm_line AS l1
INNER JOIN planet_osm_line AS l2
ON ST_Intersects(l1.way, l2.way)
WHERE l1.highway IS NOT NULL
AND l1.osm_id != 126021312
AND l2.osm_id = 126021312
```

The EXPLAIN of it shows PostgreSQL seems to be doing what I wanted in the first place:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=6.80..577.98 rows=7451 width=1108)
  ->  Index Scan using planet_osm_line_pkey on planet_osm_line l2  (cost=0.43..3.76 rows=2 width=249)
      Index Cond: (osm_id = 126021312)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on planet_osm_line l1  (cost=6.37..286.48 rows=63 width=1108)
        Recheck Cond: (way && l2.way)
        Filter: ((highway IS NOT NULL) AND (osm_id <> 126021312) AND _st_intersects(way, l2.way))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on planet_osm_line_index  (cost=0.00..6.36 rows=206 width=0)
            Index Cond: (way && l2.way)
```

I'm still curious about why the first query didn't behave like this one, though.

Comment: Because the planner doesn't see a geometry column, but a table expression. The INNER JOIN syntax is the same as the explicit CROSS JOIN when you have an intersects in the where clause. I personally find the CROSS JOIN (ie, the comma between two tables) more natural, as you can't really inner join on a geometric join.